# skip last Git commit

Tags: git, commit

I committed several files that I pushed like that on my dev computer:

```
C1-C2-C3-C4
```

And now on my prod environnement I do not want to pull the C2-C3 commits.
I want directly go from C1 to C4.
I do not want Git to apply changes mades on my files during C2 and C3.

Comment: Try git cherry-pick: http://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick

Comment: Do you want to remove C2-C3 forever or just not push it yet?

Comment: I want to keep C2-C3, but not push them.

Answer (score 1):

An easy way to do this is

- use `git log` to find the hash for the oldest commit you are interested in
- use `git rebase -i 29385792875947534` (or whatever the hash is)

Then delete the commits you are not interested (C2, C3) in and you will have the desired 
output

Comment: Here, 'delete' means removing the corresponding line from the editor that pops up when you enter `git rebase -i <commit>`. It will say `pick <commit>` and you want to remove that entire line.